# HMAC-SHA256 hash generation with iteration to make it even harder

Tags: php, hash, hmac

I'm trying generating HMAC-SHA256 for a application which validate data on its server with same mechanism which we need to follow.
The idea is to HASH a XML with given secret and Iteration count.
What I've done so far is :

```
$file = 'TESTXML.xml';
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$string = fread($fp,filesize($file));
$secret = 'somesecret';
$ctx = hash_init('sha256');
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret);

for ($i=0; $i < 2481 ; $i++) {
    hash_update($ctx, $sig);
}
$hash = hash_final($ctx, true);
echo base64_encode($hash);
```

But the output is different than the JAVA code provided by the company which need this implemented.

I know I'm near the solution but I feel I'm missing something really stupid.

**JAVA code:**

```
private static String generateHash(final InputStream is, final int iteration, final String key) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        Mac sha256_HMAC;
        sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        final SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
            sha256_HMAC.update(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byte[] digestValue = sha256_HMAC.doFinal();
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
            sha256_HMAC.reset();
            digestValue = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(digestValue);
        }
        final String generatedHash = Base64.encodeBase64String(digestValue);
        return generatedHash;
    }
```

Comment: Try using `hash_init('sha256', HASH_HMAC, $secret)` and then `$string = hash_update($ctx, $string);`  and without using `hash_hmac` directly at all. that seems to be the only difference with the Java function

Comment: @apokryfos I tried .. but not matching the output with JAVA code, I tried $hash = hash_final($ctx, true);
echo base64_encode($hash); 

and also putting hash_update in for loop.